# Dynamic Image not appearing in React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying create a component that genrates an image  based on the `prop` that is passed.  The component first checks the `prop` using a `switch` statement, then sets the path of the image source in the variable `path`. I know the issue is with the `path` variable, because if I set the `src` attribute to an external image source, it works just fine.

I also know that another workaround would be to import all the images using using

```
import JamaicaFlag from '../images/united-staes.png'
import USFlag from '../images/united-staes.png'
```

and then

`<StaticImage src={USFlage} src={this.props.alt} />`

but that wouldn't be an ideal option since it requires importing all the images.

```
/* Flag.js - Component that returns an image of the flag
 * depending on the country passed in throught props.
 * The prop country is specified by using Alpha-2 code
 */

import * as React from "react"
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

class Flag extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    let path = "../images/flags/jamaica.png"
    let style = { width: "30px" }

    switch (this.props.country) {
      case "JM":
        path = "../images/flags/jamaica.png"
        break

      case "TT":
        path = "../images/flags/trinidad.png"
        break

      case "BB":
        path = "../images/flags/barbados.jpeg"
        style = { width: "40px" }
        break

      case "KY":
        path = "../images/flags/cayman-slands.png"
        break

      case "US":
        path = "../images/flags/united-states.png"
        break

      default:
        // Defaults to Jamaica
        path = "../images/flags/jamaica.png"
    }

    return (
      <>
        <StaticImage src={path} alt={this.props.alt} style={style} />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Flag
```

The component is used by simply

`<Flag country="US" alt="Switch to US site" />`

This also does not work

`<StaticImage src={require(path)} alt={this.props.alt} style={style} />`

[image: Image of the output -- The flag should be displayed right were the blue curved-edge rectangle is on the menu]

It should look a little something like this

[image: Another issue I'm having is pushing the image a bit more over to the right but nothign seems to work, but that's for another day :)]

What changes are needed to make this work? Here is the full component file.

Comment: Try changing `{require(path)}` to `{require(path).default}` and see if it works

Comment: Why not place all the flag images in the static folder and name them according to the country code (e.g `/images/flags/JM.png`) and eliminate the switch and imports altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `props` along with `StaticImage`. It's a known restriction. From [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image#restrictions-on-using-staticimage):

> The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
> restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
> to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
> them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
> function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
> variables within the component’s local scope

Basically, because image sources need to be statically analyzed, can't be used out-scoped from the image component itself or from a property.

Since `StaticImage` is not an option, you can use `require` to import the image as an asset that webpack can trace using the standard `<img>` tag:

```
<img src={require(path)} alt={this.props.alt} style={style} />
```